# Detect virtualized environment with Delphi 64-bit?

Tags: delphi, assembly, virtual-machine, x86-64, vmware

```
// VMware detection as described by Elias Bachaalany
function IsInsideVMware: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  try
    asm
      push edx;
      push ecx;
      push ebx;

      mov eax, 'VMXh';
      mov ebx, 0;
      mov ecx, 10;
      mov edx, 'VX';

      in eax, dx;

      cmp ebx, 'VMXh';
      setz [Result];

      pop ebx;
      pop ecx;
      pop edx;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;


function IsRunningUnderHyperV: BOOL; stdcall;
var
  VMBranding: array[0..12] of AnsiChar;
begin
  asm
    mov eax, $40000000;
    cpuid;
        mov dword ptr [VMBranding+0], ebx;  // Get the VM branding string
        mov dword ptr [VMBranding+4], ecx;
        mov dword ptr [VMBranding+8], edx;
  end;
  VMBranding[12] := #0;
  Result := CompareText(String(VMBranding), 'Microsoft Hv') = 0;
end;
```

How can this be done for 64-bit Delphi application?

If I try to compile it as 64-bit I get message "Unsupported language feature: ASM" and "Operand size mismatch". I know that you need to separate asm code from pascal code and registers are different but have no idea how to do it?

Comment: Did you read Delphi's documentation yet? [Using Inline Assembly Code](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code)

Comment: Why do you need to detect virtualization?

Comment: Yes. Changed code to eliminate "Unsuported language feature: ASM" and solved it but now have "E2116 Invalid combination of opcode and operands". Registers needs to be changed to 64-bit but dont know which to use?

Comment: I don't want users to be able to run my program in virtual machine.

Comment: You can't use `in` in user mode. All VMM will set bit 31 of `ecx` when doing `cpuid` with `eax=1`. This bit is zero on physical machines, 1 on para-virtualized VMs. There are a few checks you can perform but all are easily circumvented.  I know of only a single one that is easy and effective but there is no *good* reason to not want users to run a program inside a virtual machine. VMs are everywhere even without the user knowing! The only programs that don't want to be run in VMs are malwares, so they can't be analyzed by automated sandboxes.

Comment: Tried to use eax -> rax and so on registries but getting error. If user can register program in VM then he can copy it numerous times.

Comment: "If user can register program in VM then he can copy it numerous times" then you need to revise your licensing scheme. There are many hypervisors out there besides vmware and hyperV...

Answer (score 1):

At end, I have used this solution for 32/64-bit.

```
var
  LFlag: Cardinal;

//================================= VMWare =====================================

procedure TryVMWare;
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  asm
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    mov eax, 'VMXh'
    mov ecx, 0Ah
    mov dx, 'VX'
    in eax, dx
    mov LFlag, ebx
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax
  end;
{$ENDIF CPUX86}
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
  asm
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx
    mov eax, 'VMXh'
    mov ecx, 0Ah
    mov dx, 'VX'
    in eax, dx
    mov LFlag, ebx
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    pop rax
  end;
{$ENDIF CPUX64}

function IsInsideVMware: Boolean;
begin
  LFlag := 0;
  try
    TryVMWare;
  except
  end;
  Result := LFlag = $564D5868;
end;
```

As for detecting other VM brands in 64-bit I have used code from:

https://github.com/JBontes/FastCode/blob/master/FastcodeCPUID.pas

Code is updated to run and compile as x64 bit and detect virtual machines brands.

Comment: .data
    LFlag DWORD ?

.code

QueryVMWareBackdoorAssembly PROC
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx
    mov eax, 'VMXh'
    mov ecx, 0Ah
    mov dx, 'VX'
    in eax, dx
    mov LFlag, ebx
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    ret
QueryVMWareBackdoorAssembly ENDP

END



For .asm file as a C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

The JEDI `JclSysInfo.GetCpuInfo()` function gets just about everything you'd ever want to know about the CPU, and returns the physical device's characteristics regardless of whether you're in a VM or on the root OS.  The easiest way to detect most VMs is to get the CPUID string:

```
function GetVMBranding: String;
var
  VMBranding: array[0..12] of AnsiChar;
begin
  asm
    mov eax, $40000000;
    cpuid;
    mov dword ptr [VMBranding+0], ebx;  // Get the VM branding string
    mov dword ptr [VMBranding+4], ecx;
    mov dword ptr [VMBranding+8], edx;
  end;
  VMBranding[12] := #0;
  Result := String(VMBranding);
end;
```

Then compare it to known strings (a list can be found at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#:~:text=In%20the%20x86%20architecture%2C%20the,and%20SL%2Denhanced%20486%20processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#:%7E:text=In%20the%20x86%20architecture%2C%20the,and%20SL%2Denhanced%20486%20processors))  However, there are a couple of important caveats:

1. The CPUID query will return the Hyper-V signature if Hyper-V is installed, whether or not you're running on the root OS or in a VM.  This is because once Hyper-V is installed, its hypervisor is managing threads even for the root OS.  I have not found a way yet to detect actually running inside a Hyper-V VM.
2. VirtualBox and WINE require separate methods of detection.  WINE adds some functions to NTDLL.DLL, so looking for those functions is a reliable way to detect WINE.  For VirtualBox, you have to look for its service in the list of running processes.

```
function CheckWine: Boolean;
var
  hnd: THandle;
  wine_get_version: function : pchar; {$IFDEF Win32} stdcall; {$ENDIF}
  wine_unix2fn: procedure (p1:pointer; p2:pointer); {$IFDEF Win32} stdcall; {$ENDIF}
begin
  Result := False;
  hnd := LoadLibrary('ntdll.dll');
  if hnd > 32 then begin
    wine_get_version := GetProcAddress(hnd, 'wine_get_version');
    wine_unix2fn := GetProcAddress(hnd, 'wine_nt_to_unix_file_name');
    if assigned(wine_get_version) or assigned(wine_unix2fn) then
       Result := True;
    FreeLibrary(hnd);
  end;
end;

//uses WinApi.TlHelp32
function CheckVirtualBox: Boolean;
var
  handle: THandle;
  procinfo: ProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result   := False;
  handle   := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  procinfo.dwSize := sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
  while(Process32Next(handle, procinfo)) do begin
    if (POS('VBoxService.exe', procinfo.szExeFile) > 0) then begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  CloseHandle(handle);
end;
```